# Injecting a dependency that is a static variable in a class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, static-classes

A WinForms application uses the following "configuration class" (partial code):

```
public class Configuration
{
    public static Project currentProject;
}
```

Many other classes in the application currently use this `Project` variable, for example:

```
public class Controller
{
    public void processSomething()
    {
        Configuration.currentProject.doSomething();
    }
}
```

For the purposes of loose coupling, I want to be able to inject a `Project` variable as a dependency. The problem is, the `Configuration.currentProject` value might change at runtime. How should this be dealt with? Can passing it by reference solve it?

Comment: It is a WinForms app.

Comment: `public static Project currentProject;` Is it an option to make that _not_ static?

Comment: @mjwills probably not, but I will look into it. For now let us assume that must be static.

Comment: If you make it a singleton object in your IoC, then you don't have to make it static.

Comment: What IoC container do you use?

Comment: @mjwills none, I do it "manually".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest passing in a `Func<IProject>` or `Func<Project>`. This will allow you to nicely handle changes to `Configuration.currentProject` (since invoking the function will always see the current value of the `static`) and also allow relatively easy writing of unit tests.

That being said, I'd strongly encourage you to move away from use of `static` and manual dependency injection. If you used a IoC container (e.g. Autofac) then `Func` and singleton support (without `static`) will likely be built in.

Comment: How to make a `Func<IProject>` manipulate the static variable in the `Configuration` class? From my understanding, a `Func` needs to point to some method which *returns* a value.

Comment: It can set any properties etc that you want to in the `Project` instance it is passed. Either way, that is now a new question (i.e. you never said you needed that in your original question - you said it might change, but it wasn't clear that the class taking the dependency was the one changing it). So you may be best to write up a new question for that @Al2110.

Comment: Another option would be to take two dependencies - the second being `IProjectSetter` which has a method that sets `Configuration.currentProject`. Thus most consumers take a dependency on the `Func`, but if a particular code path needs to also set then it takes a second dependency (on `IProjectSetter`).